# Asking about a Loop problem, For Loop not working

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

Hello in this code when I am seeing the output, it is not working.

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   var x = '2 × ' +i +' = ' +2*i +'<br>';
};
document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p id="table"></p>
```

I expected it to give the text to that paragraph.
This text: 2 × 1 = 2
And upto 2 × 10 = 20
Also there was `<br>` for next line.

I tried to declare x outside also but still it is not working:

The modified code inside `<script>`

```js
var x;
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   x = '2 × ' +i +' = ' +2*i +'<br>';
};
document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p id="table"></p>
```

Comment: You are always overwriting `x`.  Try `x += ...` so you'll append to it instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting `x` on each iteration of the loop.

Initialize `x` to an empty string, then use `+=` to concatenate to it.

```js
var x = '';
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   x += '2 × ' +i +' = ' +2*i +'<br>';
};
document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p id="table"></p>
```

Comment: Yes you told me that I am overwritting but I have a question why it is working in that [the way you showed] way also.

Comment: Is there anything about scopes?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p id="table"></p>

<script>
  let x = '';  // set to empty space

  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    x += '2 × ' + i +' = ' + 2*i +'<br>';  // use +=
  };

  document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = x;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to have all x values. You need to append them.

Try this:

```js
var x = ''; // added a default value
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   // switched to += (concatenation)
   x += '2 × ' + i +' = ' + 2*i + '<br>';
}

document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = x;
```